# Как создать отчет с профилями пользователя 1С?

Tags: 1с

Мне нужно сделать вот такой отчет в расширениях базы

```
              | Пользователь 1 | Пользователь 2
Администратор | x              | x
Бухгалтер     |                |
Финансист     |                | x
```

Первый столбец - это профили, которые есть в базе. В шапке все пользователи базы. А внутри таблицы ячейки с `x`, если у данного пользователя есть роль, и пустая ячейка, если нет.

Я знаю как заполнить профили и пользователей через макет с помощью запросов, через СКД пока не понятно как это делать. А центральную часть вообще не знаю как высчитывать. Как это можно сделать?

UPD1:
Понял как через СКД сделать строку с пользователями с помощью справочника пользователей. Но есть ли справочник с профилями?

Comment: Под профилями вы подразумеваете роли пользователей БД, создаваемые через конфигуратор?

Comment: @kio имею ввиду группу ролей

Comment: Есть много готовых инструментов для такого.

Comment: @shitslark Тогда поищите реализацию шахматки по группам прав/ролей, как заметили выше, примеров довольно много. Если же вам нужно работать с  ролями БД, то их можно вытянуть через метаданные.

Comment: @kio можете подсказать, куда стоит посмотреть, чтобы найти информацию по внутреннему заполнению таблицы с крестиками. Все это время искал, но во всех статьях приводятся простые примеры с отчетом-списком

Comment: @shitslark этот тип отчета называется шахматкой. Через СКД реализуется довольно просто. Для примера воспользуйтесь конструктором. А вот если захотите вручную собрать отчет, то будут сложности.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужны именно Профили/Группы доступа, то информацию найдёте в соответствующих справочниках. Если надо определить названия этих справочников, - откройте Форму элемента, нажмите "*получить ссылку*" (в ссылке будет название справочника)

Создать такой отчет можно создать без использования СКД с помощью присоединения Областей макета;

В случае если задача стоит - строго использовать СКД, наилучшая универсальная техника описана тут: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9Shd4TGmJ8